# Masking areas outside of polygon using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to "mask" raster cells that are outside of a polygon layer, setting them to "NoData". Also, I need to use GDAL, rather than R which I normally use, because the raster is too large to fit in memory.

So far, my workflow is -

```sh
## Burn -9999 into areas outside of polygons
gdal_rasterize -i -b 1 -b 2 -burn -9999 -l pol pol.shp modis_south_copy.tif

## Set -9999 to NoData
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata -9999 modis_south_copy.tif modis_south_copy1.tif
```

The first expression sets all cells that are outside of polygon `pol.shp` in raster `modis_south.copy.tif` to -9999. The second expression creates a new raster `modis_south_copy1.tif` where the value -9999 is replaced with NoData.

Here is a graphical illustration of the process:

I start with a raster named `modis_south_copy.tif`, here is an image of the first four bands -

[image]

After running the first expression with `gdal_rasterize`, areas outside `pol.shp` are replaced with -9999 -

[image]

Finally, after the second expression with `gdal_translate`, the copy `modis_south_copy1.tif` has -9999 replaced with to NoData -

[image]

The input files `modis_south.tif` and `pol.shp` are available here - 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b9wtqgpylohuerx/AACyzhzfeGqgthGxMe1ZfW1pa?dl=0

Can I somehow specify that I want to `-burn NoData` instead of `-burn -9999`, in `gdal_rasterize` and, if so, what is the right syntax? (`-burn NoData` is just a guess and doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like R then I recommend gdalUtils.  It interfaces R directly to GDAL, allowing you to use it in a more R-like way; you'll need to write data to disk for GDAL to work with it.  The following will mask data to an input geom.

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

## r raster
## geom SpatialPolygon
## outfile path to save masked data
ezmask <- function(r, geom, outfile, dstnodata='None', ...) {
    tmpd <- tempdir(check=TRUE)
    tmpf <- tempfile(fileext='.tif')
    rgdal::writeOGR(geom, tmpd, 'cutline', driver='ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=TRUE)
    raster::writeRaster(r, tmpf)
    gdalUtils::gdalwarp(tmpf, outfile, cutline=tmpd, cl='cutline', dstnodata=dstnodata, ...)
}

## assuming data is available in home directory
rModis <- raster('~/modis_south.tif')
spPol <- readOGR('~/pol.shp')
ezmask(rModis, spPol, 'masked_modis_south.tif')
rModisMasked <- raster('masked_modis_south.tif')
plot(rModisMasked, ylim=c(34e5, 355e4))

## pass arguments expected by gdalwarp to alter behavior
ezmask(rModis, spPol, 'masked_modis_south.tif', dstnodata=-9999, overwrite=TRUE)

## happy mapping!
```

[image: modis masked]

Comment: Thanks! this doesn't work for me yet - will see if I can figure out why. The error message is `ERROR 5: -tap option cannot be used without using -tr.`.

Comment: oh just remove tap.  The tr option is to resample to a target resolution--if you need to resample multiple rasters then use tap to ensure they align.  I've edited my answer to remove it.

Comment: This writes a raster 50 times larger in file size, with all cells either 0 or 'NoData', and at a different CRS and resolution... Not what I needed, but thanks anyway for your time looking into it!

Comment: that's odd.  I'll fetch your data today and test it.  did you give it a tr argument?  that would change resolution, otherwise I don't see how that's possible.  the CRS changed because I set it to default to 4326--a bad assumption that I'll remove.

Comment: please copy the new function and try it out.  I've added a workflow demonstration and plot of results.  pass named arguments to alter behavior--you might have inadvertently done this if you passed an argument named tr, which sets a new resolution.

Comment: When I reach the `ezmask` command I get an error `ERROR 4: Attempt to create new tiff file `~/masked_modis_south.tif' failed: No such file or directory`

Comment: you may need to replace '~/' with an absolute path. Are you on windows?  R may convert '~/' to windows home directory, so loading up the data worked, but GDAL may not and so when ezmask tries to call gdalwarp with the outfile, GDAL may complain.  Replace '~/' with an absolute path--eg outfile="C:\Users\mdorman\masked_modis_south.tif", or where ever you'd like to save it.  Also, if the file already exists be sure to pass overwrite=TRUE to tell GDAL it's OK to overwrite.

Comment: I'm on Linux. You're right, using an expanded path, such as `/home/michael/masked_modis_south.tif`, works. The function now creates a new file `masked_modis_south.tif` where specified areas area are masked, so I'll accept the answer - thanks! However, the origin and extent of the new raster are not exactly the same as in `modis_south.tif`, so I still need to look for another solution.

Comment: the te and crop_to_cutline were cropping the extent to that of the shapefile.  I removed them and also replaced the relative paths so hopeully the MWE work better :)  It should now behave like you want.  If you decide you want to crop again it seems that passing crop_to_cutline=TRUE to ezmask should work (the te is unnecessary if crop_to_cutline is TRUE)